# What are the dependencies of com.android.settings(ICS)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to make a working build of ICS Settings application in `eclipse`(`com.android.settings`).  I imported it from https://github.com/tpruvot/android_packages_apps_Settings/tree/ics . However I'm getting many class not found errors and compilation failure. What are the dependencies of `com.android.settings`. How do I add them to the `eclipse` project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at this

https://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-2-hacking-around/

1 midify the ADT

2 modify the jar files

(your going to need to do this for everything in "/system/framework/". remove the android.jar from the build path and add in all the middified ".jar" files found in "/system/framework/")

^^^ignore all this, ill upload the files when im done sorting them. been trying for a wile my self as well.